# Reference issue in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, interop, reference

In my program I use `Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library` to automate Word and my system has Office2007 installed. If i pack this project and gives to my customer, it causes any problem?

My customer's computer should have Office 2007 installed in it for working of my program? What happens if he has only Office2003? If any problems is caused what is correct method to solve it or dynamically change the reference back to `11.0 Object Library`?

When I checked "My Reference" from Project properties window, it lists three references:

```
Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library --> vpp\obj\x86\Debug\Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 --> vpp\obj\x86\Debug\Interop.VBIDE.dll
Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library --> vpp\obj\x86\Debug\Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
```

These three dlls are in my debug folder. So it will work in my customer's computer?

Comment: have you included the dependencies in you project setup???

Comment: those 3 files ? Yes will include it(i didn't create the setup files yet) in the application folder. Or they should be in system folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using early binding you may get error described in [The Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly version is higher than referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888950/assembly-microsoft-office-interop-word-version-14-0-0-0-culture-neutral) (it's C# example but in VB it's going to look similar).

About differences between late binding and early binding you can read in [Binding for Office automation servers with Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902/en-us) (still C# eaxamples) and [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115/en-us) describes how to do it in VB.

Code might look like this (example from [VBA – Word – Open Word using Late Binding](http://www.devhut.net/2010/09/03/vba-word-open-word-using-late-binding/)):

```
Sub LaunchWord()
Dim objApp As Object

    'See if Word is already running
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Launch a new instance of Word
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Set objApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user (if wanted)
    End If

Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "MS Access has generated the following error" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & _
    Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error Source: LaunchWord" & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & _
    Err.Description, vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**Added:**

"Late binding" means "no intellisense", so have look at [Take advantage of Intellisense when writing late bound code](http://www.codeforexcelandoutlook.com/blog/2008/11/take-advantage-of-intellisense-when-writing-late-bound-code/).

Comment: thank you. So I should remove the reference and use the GetType() along with InvokeMember() ? Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902/

That is tough because there is no intellisense popping out with suggestion.

Comment: @VppMan, you are right (there are pros and cons), check my edit "added" section.

Comment: ok. but how to access the various constants ? Functions can be invoked using InvokeMember() of that Object.

Comment: You will also need Option Strict Off :(